# Does giving consent to treat an unconscious relative make me financially liable?

Tags: liability, medical-bill

If a person is unconscious at the hospital and needs treatment, the hospital may try to reach a relative to give consent to treat.  If that relative gives consent to treat, does that make them financially liable for medical bills?

Comment: I hope not. The idea is to find someone who is presumably familiar with the patient's wishes, not to find someone for whom the decision to treat will be based solely on financial considerations. In any case, this requires a jurisdiction to answer.

Comment: The patient still gets the bill, but if the patient's wishes were disregarded by the relative perhaps a lawsuit could follow, better asked on law.stackexchange.com though.

Comment: Where is this relative hospitalized? In a country with universal coverage there will be no bill, in other places there might be a small bill, and in other places the bill might be gigantic.

Comment: This is in California, USA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hospital has paperwork you need to sign to accept financial responsibility for the cost of care. If they have no paperwork and you aren't the patient they really have no way to go after you for the bill.

They WILL try to get someone (anyone) to sign that paperwork, so read any papers you fill out VERY carefully.

Note: Technically a verbal agreement (to pay) is a binding contract, but usually very hard to enforce. So I wouldn't worry about that unless you explicitly said "I agree to pay for this" either in writing or verbally.